# gl_deletebuffers not working in a separate thread

Tags: opengl, memory-leaks, glfw

In my rendering application if i run the render function in the main loop than everything works fine but if i take the rendering function to another thread than the destructor of the objects is not able to release the buffer.

when any object gets destroyed

The destructor for the objects are called but it seems as if gl_deletebuffers are not able to release the buffer.

How i came to this conclusion

1) when i run everthing in the main loop and if i create a object and the VAO number for the object is 1

2) after destroying the object the next object VAO is also assigned number 1.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

1) But when Rendering part goes to a seprate thread than VAO number keeps on incrementing with every object

2) System Ram memory also keeps increasing and when i close the application than only the memory is released.

3) Destructor for objects is definitely called when i delete a object but it seems as if destructor has not been able to release the buffer.

```
 //#define GLEW_STATIC

#include <gl\glew.h>
#include <glfw3.h>
#include "TreeModel.h"
#include "ui_WavefrontRenderer.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <thread>

#define FPS_WANTED 60

const double limitFPS = 1.0 / 50.0;

Container cont;
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;


void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);
GLFWwindow* window = nullptr;
void RenderThread(WavefrontRenderer* w)
{       
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    GLenum GlewInitResult;
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GlewInitResult = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != GlewInitResult)   // Check if glew is initialized properly
    {
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setText("Not able to Initialize Glew");
        msgBox.exec();
        glfwTerminate();
    }

    if (window == NULL)
    {
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setText("Not able to create GL Window");
        msgBox.exec();
        glfwTerminate();
        //return -1;
    }

    w->InitData();  
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);   
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);
        // - Measure time   
        glClearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
        w->render(); // DO the Rendering        
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    }   
    glfwTerminate();
    std::terminate();
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    cont.SetName("RootItem");
    TreeModel* model = new TreeModel("RootElement", &cont);
    WavefrontRenderer w(model);
    w.show();
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "Renderer", nullptr, nullptr);   // Create the render 

window
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(0);
    std::thread renderThread(RenderThread, &w);
    renderThread.detach();  
    return a.exec();
    return 0;
}
```

Class defination for a Object

the render function w->render() calls the draw() function of a object.

The Base class has a virtual destructor.

```
#include "Triangle.h"
#include "qdebug.h"
#include "qmessagebox.h"

float verticesTriangle[] = {
    -50.0f, -50.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f , 0.0f,1.0f    ,0.0f, 0.0f,
     50.0f, -50.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f , 0.0f,1.0f    ,1.0f, 0.0f,
     0.0f,  50.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,1.0f     ,0.5f, 1.0f
};

Triangle::Triangle() : Geometry("TRIANGLE", true)
{       
    this->isInited = 0;
    this->m_VBO = 0;
    this->m_VAO = 0;
    this->iNumsToDraw = 0;
    this->isChanged = true;
}

Triangle::Triangle(const Triangle& triangle) : Geometry( triangle )
{
    CleanUp();
    this->isInited = 0;
    this->m_VBO = 0;
    this->m_VAO = 0;
    this->iNumsToDraw = triangle.iNumsToDraw;
    this->isChanged = true;
    this->shader = ResourceManager::GetShader("BasicShader");
    iEntries = 3;
}

Triangle& Triangle::operator=(const Triangle& triangle)
{
    CleanUp();
    Geometry::operator=(triangle);
    this->isInited = 0;
    this->m_VBO = 0;
    this->m_VAO = 0;
    this->iNumsToDraw = triangle.iNumsToDraw;
    this->isChanged = true;
    this->shader = ResourceManager::GetShader("BasicShader");
    return (*this);
}

void Triangle::init()
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &m_VBO);
    glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verticesTriangle), verticesTriangle, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    isInited = true;
}

void Triangle::CleanUp()
{
    if (!this->isInited)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (this->m_VAO)
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &this->m_VAO);

    if (this->m_VBO)
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &this->m_VBO);

    this->isInited = false;
}

void Triangle::draw()
{
    if (isChanged)
    {
        init();
        isChanged = false;
    }
    this->shader.Use();
    glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

Triangle::~Triangle()
{
    if (this->m_VAO)
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &this->m_VAO);

    if (this->m_VBO)
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &this->m_VBO);


    this->isInited = false;
}
```

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/intro_guide.html#thread_safety): `"Most GLFW functions must only be called from the main thread (the thread that calls main)..."`.  So I'm not sure what you're doing is supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL contexts are thread local state:

- Every thread has exactly one or no OpenGL contexts active in it at any given time.
- Each OpenGL context must be active in no or exactly one thread at any given time.
- OpenGL contexts are not automatically migrated between thread.

I.e. if you don't explicitly unmake current the OpenGL context in question on the threads it's currently active, and subsequently make it active on the thread you're calling `glDeleteBuffers` on, the call on that will have no effect; on the context you expected it to have an effect on, at least.